# How do I use svg icons from Font Awesome in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, svg, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

How do I use svg from Font Awesome 5.5 as icons in Bootstrap 4?

I want do use Font Awesome icons in Bootstrap 4. How do I do that in the best way? I have downloaded the svg-files and can use them as a normal image but it is how it should be done?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Namn</label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text"><img src="img/svgs/regular/address-book.svg" width="20px" height="20px" alt="Name"></div>
</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="" value="" autofocus>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the SVGs?  Why not just use the font in the normal way.

Comment: Best way to use the font indeed. But if you want to use the svg's, just add a cssClass to it and a css to control the size.

Comment: Because everywhere on the internet it says that fonts no longer should be used as icons (only fonts), but replaced with svg. I like Font Awesome because they have lot of icons.

Answer (score 2):

go to fontawesome website click on the start from the navigation bar, then add the svg cdn on your project.

https://fontawesome.com/start

this is the cdn for svg icons

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```